# Where can I get a stable Nvidia driver for GeForce 635m?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I tried to install a driver for GPU GeForce 635m Kubuntu system, but the last 3 times I tried to update it failed.

When I install the drivers and try to select the newest versions from the list (331, 340, etc), after reboot I get a black blank screen and I can't repair the video drivers.

Now my laptop works only with Intel HD graphics.

How can I install a stable driver for my GPU?

Comment: How are you installing the drivers? Using the binaries on NVIDIA's website, or from the Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: Also, you might be interested in installing bumblebee along with the binary drivers, since bumblebee allows you to run commands with the NVIDIA GPU, turning on only when needed (which saves power, might be important seeing you have a mobile GPU and therefore probably a laptop) and using the Intel HD graphics at other times

Comment: I install it with command like"sudo apt-get install nvidia-331",
choose 331, 340, 306 - drivers, and it fails

Comment: zhongfu,   i can install bumblebee with new version of nvidia driver and use settings of bumblebee   for fix this problem ?

Comment: From my experience, this problem might be caused by the NVIDIA GPU not being connected directly to the display due to NVIDIA's Optimus (AFAIK). Therefore, you either need `bumblebee` or `nvidia-prime`, depending on your use case. Look at my answer for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I tried a lot of driver versions - NVIDIA 311, 303, 331...  all left me with a blank screen.

The one that worked for me was 349. This works on (Ubuntu 14.04/15.04)

So, for GeForce 635m at this moment the stable driver version is 349.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to use `bumblebee` on your computer and you're alright with logging out and logging in again every time you want to switch GPUs, then you should install `nvidia-prime`:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime nvidia-331-updates
sudo reboot now
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

This will start the desktop using the NVIDIA GPU.

Otherwise, if you want to use `bumblebee` (which runs the desktop with the Intel GPU by default and allows you to run certain commands with the NVIDIA GPU with `optirun $COMMAND`, and switches off the GPU when not in use) then you can try installing it:

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia nvidia-331-updates
```

and rebooting.